# Is there a French phrase to say 'you're not green in this'?

Tags: anglais, formulation-idiomatique

I checked the online dictionary and 'un bleu' appears to signify 'a person who is green, inexperienced'. But what is a natural French phrase to say 'I guess you're not green in this' in negative? Having the meaning that 'I guess you already have some experience in this'. I would like to say a thing like below but does this sound natural?

- 'Je suppose que tu n'es plus un bleu dans ce domaine'

---

- 'I guess you're not green in this, but when you're out there in the middle of the wild, be prepared for anything that might happen.'

Comment: Well your example is perfectly correct and natural... There is of course a lot of different ways to translate the full English sentence you're providing, but the correct translation is indeed "Etre un bleu/Ne pas être un bleu"

Comment: On a déjà ici traduit trois fois *«in the middle of the wild»* par *«en pleine nature»*. D’un qui n’en est pas à son coup d’essai en fait de vie en milieu sauvage, je dirais que cette expression sent son bleu à des lieues à la ronde... :) En pleine nature, il est plus commun de parler de l’endroit où l’on se trouve soit par son nom (élément géographique à proximité, habituellement), soit par *«en plein milieu de nulle part»*, cette dernière dénomination existant d’ailleurs aussi en anglais, *«in the middle of nowhere»*.

Answer (score 5):

In conversation, in this context I'd probably go with the phrasing:

> J’imagine que **tu n’en es pas à ton coup d’essai**, mais dès que tu te retrouves en pleine nature, sois paré à/pour toute éventualité !

Though not a literal translation, it carries the connotation of "not green anymore". As an aside: The pronoun "en" refers to whatever field you're involved in or whatever activities you're engaged in, so you don't need to add a phrase like "dans ce domaine".

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other (good) answers, another idiom may fit:

> Je suppose que tu *connais la musique*, mais lorsque que tu te retrouveras en pleine nature, sois paré à toute éventualité !

*Connaître la musique* means that you expect the person to know all rules, habits, guidelines, etc, because they have done it several times.

Answer (score 2):

You could say this in a number of ways, but my instinct would be to say:

> Je suppose que tu **n'es plus novice** dans le domaine ; néanmoins, lorsque tu te retrouves en pleine nature, sois prêt(e) à toute éventualité !

Notice that I prefer "le domaine" as opposed to "ce domaine".  Whilst you can definitely say either one, using the determiner "le" in this instance seems more natural than the demonstrative pronoun "ce".

Comment: Bien que « n'es plus novice » soit correct (adj) on utilise plutôt « n'es plus un novice » ; lorsque l'activité est spécifique « le/la » sont utilisés : plus un novice dans l'enseignement, plus un novice dans la navigation aérienne, etc. Cependant, dans le cas présent il s'agit d'une qualification générale de qqc dont il vient d'être question et en français le démonstratif est indiqué : ce domaine ; on dit bien en anglais « He is an expert in the/this  field. » et c'est peu être cela aussi qui vous donne l'impression que « le » convient mieux, mais je ne crois pas que vous puissiez le trouver.

Comment: Je trouve l'usage de l'adjectif très naturel. Peut-être une différence d'usage locale, chez moi (et John), ou alors chez @user168676...

Comment: Je ne dirais pas que l'option avec l'adjectif manque de naturel, elle me parait moins courante, mais comme vous me parlez de cela maintenant j'y pense de nouveau et je vois qu'en fait je suis passablement dans l'erreur : « je suis novice », bien qu'il soit de moins en moins utilisé au fil du temps (tout au moins à l'écrit) est quand même plus courant; voyez l'ngram suivant. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plus+novice%2Cplus+un+novice&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplus%20novice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplus%20un%20novice%3B%2Cc0

Comment: J'ai du mal à distinguer entre une « activité spécifique » et une « qualification générale » dans ce cas.  Comment peut-on savoir si l'activité est assez spécifique pour employer le déterminant « le » ou assez générale pour utiliser le démonstratif « ce » lorsqu'il s'agit d'une phrase subjective ?  D'ailleurs, ce n'était pas la langue anglaise qui m'a donné l'impression qu'il fallait mieux dire « le domaine » ; justement, en anglais on dirait plutôt « this » (comme la phrase originale du demandeur), ce qui se traduit par « ce » en français.  J'ai trouvé, à tort évidemment, « le » plus naturel.

Comment: Je me suis mal exprimé; le locuteur parle de domaine, donc s'il parle généralement on doit utiliser « un » parce que l'on ne sait pas duquel il s'agit; ici ce n'est pas le cas, il s'agit d'un domaine **dont il vient d'être question** dans les phrases qui ont précédé, pour cette raison on le rappelle en utilisant le démonstratif (« ce » et pas « le »), en quelque sorte on spécifie  quel est le domaine (et mon terme était contradictoire);  donc ne pensez plus à cette opposition (spécifique/ activité générale) ; je vous demande de m'excuser et de ne pas hésiter à me demander des précisions.

Comment: Supposons maintenant que le domaine en question ait été par exemple la géographie et que le locuteur n'ait pas voulu y référer généralement (domaine d'étude) et donc qu'il n'ait pas voulu dire « ce domaine » ; alors il aurait dit ou écrit « **la** géographie » mais la raison ce cet article défini c'est simplement que en français on n'utilise pas la forme zéro article dans ce contexte  « plus novice dans la géographie » alors qu'en anglais on aurait « not novice in geography » ; noter que si l'on change le mot ( « en » pour « dans ») il n'y a plus de différence : « plus novice en géographie ».

Comment: Merci pour ces explications @user168676 ; je pense désormais mieux comprendre.